# MySQL auto-increment based on group

Tags: mysql, mariadb, auto-increment

The problem is related to autoincrement with mysql. What I'm trying to achieve is to increment an ID value based on the customer number. So basically i insert data sets without any order into a table. Each time a new customer is inserted, i would like the id column to be incremented, but of course kept for every row related to the customer, see the table below. Is there any way to achieve that via sql? I tried my luck with multiple primary keys and also looked into partioning, but was not able to figure it out by myself.

[image: test table]

Comment: What's the purpose of this new column?  It appears redundant - as you've already got a customer ID column.

Comment: I need it for an import into our ERP-System, which requires it as I described it. I was just wondering if it possible to get the behaviour directly via sql, otherwise i'm going to edit my table in excel after i exported it.

Comment: Aha.  That makes sense!  Personally I'd use a stored procedure, either creating a temporary table (or just outputting the result set, if you system can support that), doing it procedurally.  I'll post a quick-and-dirty answer using a joining table.

Comment: My advice would be to just let the autoincrementing id look after itself. There's just no need to store something that can easily derived from existing data.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO autoinc (cid,info,customer)
SELECT
    COALESCE(max(cid),0) +1
    , 'A Customer 1'
    , 12345
FROM autoinc
WHERE customer = 12345;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT * from autoinc;
Empty set (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO autoinc (cid,info,customer)
    -> SELECT
    ->     COALESCE(max(cid),0) +1
    ->     , 'A Customer 1'
    ->     , 12345
    -> FROM autoinc
    -> WHERE customer = 12345;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * from autoinc;
+----+------+--------------+----------+
| id | cid  | info         | customer |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
|  1 |    1 | A Customer 1 |    12345 |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO autoinc (cid,info,customer)
    -> SELECT
    ->     COALESCE(max(cid),0) +1
    ->     , 'A Customer 1'
    ->     , 12345
    -> FROM autoinc
    -> WHERE customer = 12345;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * from autoinc;
+----+------+--------------+----------+
| id | cid  | info         | customer |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
|  1 |    1 | A Customer 1 |    12345 |
|  2 |    2 | A Customer 1 |    12345 |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO autoinc (cid,info,customer)
    -> SELECT
    ->     COALESCE(max(cid),0) +1
    ->     , 'B Customer 2'
    ->     , 9876
    -> FROM autoinc
    -> WHERE customer = 9876;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * from autoinc;
+----+------+--------------+----------+
| id | cid  | info         | customer |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
|  1 |    1 | A Customer 1 |    12345 |
|  2 |    2 | A Customer 1 |    12345 |
|  3 |    1 | B Customer 2 |     9876 |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO autoinc (cid,info,customer)
    -> SELECT
    ->     COALESCE(max(cid),0) +1
    ->     , 'A Customer 1'
    ->     , 12345
    -> FROM autoinc
    -> WHERE customer = 12345;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * from autoinc;
+----+------+--------------+----------+
| id | cid  | info         | customer |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
|  1 |    1 | A Customer 1 |    12345 |
|  2 |    2 | A Customer 1 |    12345 |
|  3 |    1 | B Customer 2 |     9876 |
|  4 |    3 | A Customer 1 |    12345 |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is not exactly what i'm looking for. I require an ouput like this :

Comment: mysql> SELECT * from autoinc;
+----+------+--------------+----------+
| id | cid  | info         | customer |
+----+------+--------------+----------+
|  1 |    1 | A Customer 1 |    12345 |
|  2 |    1 | A Customer 1 |    12345 |
|  3 |    2 | B Customer 2 |     9876 |
|  4 |    1 | A Customer 1 |    12345 |
+----+------+--------------+----------+

Comment: This is a terrible idea.

Comment: @Strawberry - why ?

Comment: Because of the potential to damage relational integrity

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is to have different values for `ID` for each customer. The easiest way to achieve this is to use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column as `PK` of your table.

It is an implementation detail that for consecutively inserted rows an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column has consecutive values. And the previous statement is not even true. It just happens some times, it is not guaranteed. If an `INSERT` statement is enclosed in a transaction that is rolled back, the value generated by that insert is skipped. Also, if an `INSERT` statements that use `ON DUPLICATE KEYS UPDATE` tries to insert many rows but some of them already exist in the table then the `ID`s generated for the duplicate keys are skipped.

**What I want to stress out is that there is no point trying to get consecutive values using an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and *it is not even possible*.**

Back to your problem, if the column `ID` is the `PK` of the table and its type is `INT AUTO_INCREMENT` then MySQL guarantees there won't be two rows having the same value in the `ID` column and this also satisfies your need to have different values for `ID` for all the rows with the same value in `customer`.

Comment: Very good (and important) point made about the non-consecutive nature of auto-incrementing columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could procedurally do this using a stored procedure, which I won't elaborate on (unless requested) as it isn't a simple query (as you're asking for).

A hacky solution would be to bulk insert into a new joining table:

```
CREATE TABLE auto_inc_customer_id (
   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   customer_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, -- Could/should add a FK constraint
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=innodb;

INSERT INTO auto_inc_customer_id SELECT NULL, DISTINCT(Customer) FROM YourExistingTable;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Comment: After reading all comments so far, which i appreciate, i believe that I am going to be much faster when i simply use a custom solution altering the colument AFTER collecting all data and not WHILE collecting it.